# How do I use "resolveRedirectTo" in Angular 1.6?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-routing, angularjs-1.6

I am trying to retrieve value from the server, and then use it as a parameter in a redirect.

I couldn't make sense of the documentation provided:

> *resolveRedirectTo* – {Function=} – a function that will (eventually) return the value to update $location URL with and trigger route redirection. In contrast to redirectTo, dependencies can be injected into resolveRedirectTo and the return value can be either a string or a promise that will be resolved to a string.

So somehow I need to join the response with the string, but I can't figure out how.

```
resolveRedirectTo: ['settingsService', function (settingsService) {
            var promise = settingsService.getSettings();
              ???
            return '/settings/' + resolved.setting[0].id;
        }],
```

Any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, I've never used the `resolveRedirectTo` "resolver", but if it seems it should work the same as any `resolve`.
According to the docs:

> resolveRedirectTo – {Function=} – a function that will (eventually)
>   return the value to update $location URL with and trigger route
>   redirection. In contrast to redirectTo, dependencies can be injected
>   into resolveRedirectTo and **the return value can be either a string or
>   a promise that will be resolved to a string**.

So, in your case, you should return the promise returned by the `getSettings` method:

```
resolveRedirectTo: ['settingsService', function (settingsService) {
    return settingsService.getSettings().then((settings)=>{
        // Use the obtained settings to calculate the URL.
        return '/settings/' + settings[0].id;
    });
}],
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to ever enter the "then" functions. It seems I get to return a promise OR s string, not a resolved promise concatenated with a string.


In resolve I solve it by using $resolve in the template,


template: "<dm-setting='$resolve.setting'></dm-setting>", I'm not sure how to use the promise in resolveRedirectTo. It might be that I have to use another approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

in `resolveRedirectTo` function you should create and return the promise which will be eventually resolved in response to the method of your http service. Besides your own service, you need to inject [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) into `resolveRedirectTo` function to create the promise. Then call it `resolve` function and pass the value returned from your service to trigger redirect with.

It works this way:

```
$routeProvider.when('/any', {
    resolveRedirectTo: function ($q, myservice) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        myservice.httpMethod()
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve('/other/' + response.data.path);
                },
                function (error) {
                    deferred.reject();
                });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```